# Ansible conditionals with with_items/nested

Tags: ansible

Given the following tasks:

```
- name: Gather security group info
  amazon.aws.ec2_group_info:
    filters:
      "tag:vpn_ports": "*"
  register: sec_group_info_output

- name: Extract security groups and ports
  set_fact:
    vpn_groups: "{{ vpn_groups + [{ 'group_id': item.group_id, 'ports': item.tags.vpn_ports.split(',') }] }}"
  with_items:
    - "{{ sec_group_info_output | json_query('security_groups') }}"
  vars:
    vpn_groups: []
  when: sec_group_info_output != []

- name: Generate list with CIDRs
  set_fact:
    vpn_rules: "{{ vpn_rules + [{ 'group_id': item.0.group_id , 'port': item.1, 'cidr': item.2 }] }}"
  with_nested:
    - "{{ vpn_groups|subelements('ports') }}"
    - "{{ cidr_ranges }}"
  vars:
    vpn_rules: []
  when: sec_group_info_output != []
```

I am trying to skip the last two tasks if the first task returns an empty set.
My understanding is that the when conditional is evaluated for every loop, and not just for the task as a whole.

The below therefor gives me:

```
TASK [security_groups : Gather security group info] ****************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [security_groups : Extract security groups and ports] *********************

TASK [security_groups : Generate list with CIDRs] ******************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "obj must be a list of dicts or a nested dict"}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=1    rescued=0    ignored=0

 Error: The command exited with status 2
```

How would I go about fixing this error? I've tried putting `|default([])` into my nested_items like below:

```
- name: Generate list with CIDRs
  set_fact:
    vpn_rules: "{{ vpn_rules + [{ 'group_id': item.0.group_id , 'port': item.1, 'cidr': item.2 }] |default([])}}"
  with_nested:
    - "{{ vpn_groups|subelements('ports') |default([])}}"
    - "{{ cidr_ranges |default([])}}"
  vars:
    vpn_rules: []
  when: sec_group_info_output != []
```

The error remains the same.
I've also tried putting both tasks in a block, but this had no effect and the error remains the same.

How would I be able to skip these tasks based on my condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, your condition is completely wrong. `sec_group_info_output` is a registered variable, so it can never be equal to an empty list. It will always be a dictionary containing information about the task execution. In order to have a chance of working as intended, it would need to be:

```yaml
  when: sec_group_info_output.security_groups != []
# more idiomatically, an empty list is false so you can just treat the value as a boolean
  when: sec_group_info_output.security_groups
# or you can check the length
  when: sec_group_info_output['security_groups'] | length > 0
```

However, in this case you don't need conditions at all. You're looping over the same list you're checking, and an empty loop will not execute any tasks. You just need a `| default([])` in the loop definition on the third task in case the second didn't execute, and everything's fine.

```yaml
    - name: Gather security group info
      amazon.aws.ec2_group_info:
        filters:
          "tag:vpn_ports": "*"
      register: sec_group_info_output

    - name: Extract security groups and ports
      set_fact:
        vpn_groups: "{{ vpn_groups | default([]) + [{ 'group_id': item.group_id, 'ports': item.tags.vpn_ports.split(',') }] }}"
      loop: "{{ sec_group_info_output.security_groups }}"

    - name: Generate list with CIDRs
      set_fact:
        vpn_rules: "{{ vpn_rules | default([]) + [{ 'group_id': item.0.0.group_id , 'port': item.0.1, 'cidr': item.1 }] }}"
      loop: "{{ vpn_groups | default([]) | subelements('ports') | product(cidr_ranges) }}"
```

`{{ vpn_groups | subelements('ports') | default([]) }}` was headed in the right direction, but you put the `default()` in the wrong place. It needs to be before the `subelements()` filter so that that filter receives an empty list, not an undefined variable.

Comment: Thank you, also appreciate you changing my with_items/nested to loops. I wasn't sure how to do that.